# Search key by value in multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Using PHP's website as a reference I'm trying to search for a key of the known value in associative array:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

The following code always returns 1, but suppose to return 120:

```
$location_key = array_search(1, array_column($locations, 'main'));
```

print_r($locations):

```
Array
(
    [120] => Array
        (
            [clientid] => 122103
            [name] => HQ
            [address] => 2013 BENSON GARDEN BLVD
            [address2] => 
            [city] => OMAHA
            [state] => NE
            [zip] => 68134
            [country] => UNITED STATES
            [lat] => 00.000
            [lng] => -0.0000
            [taxrate] => 0
            [main] => 1
            [active] => 1
            [contactid] => 14
        )

    [122] => Array
        (
            [clientid] => 122103
            [name] => Branch
            [address] => 515E E 72ND ST
            [address2] => 
            [city] => NEW YORK
            [state] => NY
            [zip] => 10021
            [country] => UNITED STATES
            [lat] => 40.766705
            [lng] => -73.952965
            [taxrate] => 0
            [main] => 0
            [active] => 1
            [contactid] => 0
        )

)
```

Not sure why PHP's website is referencing the highest up voted "User Contributed Note" which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `array_column()` doesn't keep your keys. So you first need to [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) the keys with the array from `array_column()`, e.g.

```
$location_key = array_search(1, array_combine(array_keys($locations), array_column($locations, 'main')));
```

Comment: Totally makes sense... Just wonder how come the answer from `xfoxawy at gmail dot com` on PHP's site has 235 votes with exactly same structure like mine and it doesn't work.

Comment: @AlexG Look at it closely again :) He doesn't have an associative array like you have. His one is 0,1,2,...

Comment: Hmmm.... 0,1,2 (in order) makes it an associative array compare to mine 120,122 ... ?

Comment: @AlexG It's an enumerated array starting from 0 as ever array does. Same as `array_column()`, so that is why they match up with the keys. (Do: `print_r(array_column(...));`)